# Asynchronously assigning a text file to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, asynchronous

I was looking at [Benjamin Gruenbaum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593/6409670), where he prints `result` in the body of the HTML. While he does talk extensively, him and other answers about how this works, they do not directly answer the question that is How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?

As I understand it, he (and I) wanted to be able to return the result and assign it to a variable for instance, or console.log() it outside the function `foo`.
Here is the code:

```
      foo(function (result) {
        document.body.innerHTML = result;
      });

      function foo(callback) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) { // request is done
                if (httpRequest.status === 200) { // successfully
                    callback(httpRequest.responseText); // we're calling our method
                }
            }
        };
        httpRequest.open('GET', "someFile.json");
        httpRequest.send();
      }
```

What I really want is to read the file "someFile.json" and store the corresponding string in a variable `jsonString` instead of assigning it to the body of the page, so I can do something with it somewhere else.

Comment: and you can. Just don't "do something with it" before `callback` executes and assigns it.

Comment: *"they do not directly answer the question that is How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"* Well, the direct answer would be: *you can't*, but that's not really useful. Instead we show you how to structure your code instead.

Comment: @Igor My bad, I copied the wrong part after I tried some things. I just want to assign `result` to a variable, but when I do it ends up undefined.

Comment: @FelixKling So is there no way for me to assign `result` to an existing variable instead of updating `body` without having to resort to server side programming?

Comment: You can do whatever you want *inside the callback*, e.g. `someExistingVariable = result;`. But usually there are better solution depending on your exact use case.

Comment: @FelixKling I tried creating a variable before the two function, called `var jsonString;`, but when I replace (or add after) `document.body.innerHTML = result;` the line `jsonString = result`, the variable stays undefined.

Comment: *"the variable stays undefined."* You are most likely accessing `jsonString` **before** the callback was executed (see also [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196)). And that's exactly the reason why this is not a common thing to do: You don't know when to access the variable unless you execute the code that needs to access the variable/response from the callback. Explaining this and providing solutions is the whole point of the question you are linked to!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127651/discussion-between-morganfr-and-felix-kling).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a variable if this is what you are after. Just keep in mind that the variable will only get value when `onreadystatechange` executes and assigns it.

```
  var someFileContent;

  foo(function () {
    console.log(someFileContent);
  });

  function foo(callback) {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) { // request is done
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) { // successfully
                someFileContent = httpRequest.responseText;
                callback(); // we're calling our method
            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', "someFile.json");
    httpRequest.send();
  }
```

Comment: And why would you want to do this instead of passing the value to the callback?

Comment: @FelixKling Naturally. On a small chance that this was what the OP was missing. I am planning to delete this since it is so plainly obvious.

Comment: @Igor I know I can do that, but the issue remains, while I can do whatever I want with the variable `someFileContent`, I cannot get it to be assigned outside the callback, or assign the value to another variable outside of the callback. For instance, I would like to be able to use `console.log(someFileContent)` after both those functions and use it afterwards, like counting the lines or something. But it has to happen outside the callback.

Comment: @MorganFR - the code I showed does that. Do you see the content of you expect in the browser console?

Comment: @Igor I do see what I want, but not where I want. I do not want to continue the rest of my program within the callback function. I have no interest in printing it, I want to use that data later on via a variable.

Comment: @MorganFR If by "outside the callback" you mean "before the callback", you need to get the "cause and effect" in your code straight.  `onreadystatechange`, where `someFileContent` is assigned, is the earliest moment when the content from server becomes available to client-side code.

Comment: @Igor I mean after the callback. I simply want to read the file, and store it in a variable to be used later. The callback would be a good moment to assign the content to the variable, however, the rest of the code is executed before the callback is done, and therefore nothing happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127652/discussion-between-morganfr-and-igor).